# Using Array Value as a Key in Another One

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm stuck with reading from an array. There is a source array:

```
tnails: [
    {
      mil: '/static/mini/t-icon-mil.png',
      mar: '/static/mini/t-icon-mar.png',
      brd: '/static/mini/t-icon-brd.png',
      prs: '/static/mini/t-icon-prs.png',
      pol: '/static/mini/t-icon-pol.png',
      fbr: '/static/mini/t-icon-fbr.png'
    }
  ],
```

and another one:

```
this.headers = [
        {
          mil: 'Entry No. 1',
          mar: 'Entry No. 2',
          brd: 'Entry No. 3',
          prs: 'Entry No. 4',
          pol: 'Entry No. 5',
          fbr: 'Entry No. 6'
        }
      ]
```

I'm trying to display values from `headers` array using part of `tnails` array entries as a key:

```
tn.substring(20, 23)
```

It gives values like `mil`, `mar`, etc., which I intend to use.

It is formatted this way now:

```
      <v-layout v-for="t in tnails" :key="t.id">
        <v-flex v-for="tn in t" :key="tn.id">
          <v-tooltip>
            <img :src="tn" slot="activator">
            <span>{{ headers (???) tn.substring(20, 23) }}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
```

How should I combine the data from these two arrays to make entries from `headers` displayed?

Comment: Is `tn` `tnails`? `headers[tn.substring(20, 23)]`?

Comment: Yes, it is stated here: v-for="t in tnails".

Comment: @guest271314: `headers[0][tn.substring(20, 23)]` (mind the 0 index) worked. Please post it as an answer & thank you!

Comment: I think instead of using tn.substring(20, 23) you can use tnails objects key also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to reference a property of `headers` object using the parsed string as a key

```
headers[index][tn.substring(20, 23)]
```